# Find pattern of 10 in a row and reset after a certain search string

Tags: bash, awk

I have a log file (see example below). I want to return the first line of when "Monitor is displaying image" happens 10 times in a row in a boot cycle (after "Box turned on", before "Box off"). I am guessing AWK but not sure how to implement this. Any help would be appreciated.

Example Log:

```
Box turned on.
 Monitor is NOT displaying image.
 Monitor is NOT displaying image.
 Monitor is NOT displaying image.
 Monitor is NOT displaying image.
 Monitor is NOT displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Monitor is displaying image.
 Box off.
 Pausing before reboot (10).
 Pausing before reboot (9).
 Pausing before reboot (8).
 Pausing before reboot (7).
 Pausing before reboot (6).
 Pausing before reboot (5).
 Pausing before reboot (4).
 Pausing before reboot (3).
 Pausing before reboot (2).
 Pausing before reboot (1).
 Box turned on.
```

Comment: When you say "return" do you actually mean "print" or something else (and, if so, what)? Why do you care if it's the first or last or some other line that's printed - are you looking for a line number or something in the output? What if the pattern you want to find occurs multiple times in your input file - output multiple lines or exit after the first one or something else? Edit your question to include the expected output given that input plus whatever you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/Box turned on/{f=1}
             /Box off/{f=0} 
                     f{if(/Monitor is displaying image/)c++; else c=0}
                 c==10{print; exit}' log
```

Comment: yes, I love AWK for this reason. Thanks for taking the time to reply.